# How do I get the public key of a pem file?

Tags: ssh, cryptography, bitbucket, private-key, pem

I have a `.pem` file containing my private key. However, a BitBucket deployment key has this format:

> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC3yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDfZxX2LXOJlo5MP2tLP4fmQyjIAcATwATFKwM6K3mtT7+LKx1jk6YlFlEcj2CFxJHHTy6LCdDqoVzL3iNcD+mDl7NbcNEHytZNJnFQ5lAHPxDVa9ZbLnmP1OlfUvsQS+jAt7yMSwd8gZ6McOJfp9ZUn+r5LLpjYkF+AMQFPsf+6lhSJaOjOTbsA39OJwlnnSO6HF3W2Om+8Bgdpa/E4En5RZTBwFCAvLaaXY3XgN76xCR24TwTWFicBHWeLdADGFXB7OBOv4y805fNGbNKOl3Yb21mG89aUQlYjobeLqImyIrrEhX36hEdMW/t6zZK/1I0QC//uLa+GjJoeuPW4WY3
>   ubuntu@Box

It is usually found using:

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy`

How do I extract my public key, in this format, from a `.pem` file?

Comment: it's simply `ssh-keygen -f yourPemFile.pem`

Answer (score 209, accepted):

**Copy the public key to clipboard.**

Linux

```
ssh-keygen -f private.pem -y | xclip
```

MacOS

```
ssh-keygen -f private.pem -y | pbcopy
```

**Save to file**

```
ssh-keygen -f private.pem -y > public.pub
```

Note that if your permissions are vague on the `.pem` file, then `ssh-keygen` will generate an empty `.pub` file.

You can usually fix this with:

```
chmod 400 private.pem
```

Comment: On Mac, "ssh-keygen -f Private.pem -y|pbcopy" works well.

Comment: Not sure why the different Linux and macOS commands are given. If you want the public key in a file, the "Linux" command is pretty much universal. If you want the command on a clipboard, then the macOS command is correct for macOS, and there are various Linux equivalents depending on what desktop environment you are using.

Comment: There was an edit that added that, good point changed the answer.

Answer (score 8):

JazzCat's answer works. small addition: if your permissions are vague on .pem file, ssh-keygen will generate empty .pub file.

if you see any complains on terminal about private key too open, try to narrow it using `chmod 400 private.pem` and retry above command.

ps: sorry I don't have permissions to add a comment instead of answer.