# How do I get a publickey out of my .pem file

Tags: python, ssh, terminal, key, pem

When I ran my python code (using parmiko library python) I got this error:

> Bad authentication type; allowed types: ['publickey', 'gssapi-keyex',
> 'gssapi-with-mic']

The path I supplied was to a .pem file which was my key to the server.

How do I get a public key out of this .pem file not necessarily using python?

(I am using a mac)

Here is the code I used:

```
import paramiko

def file_move(): 
    k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("Insertadress") 
    c = paramiko.SSHClient()
    c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print ("connecting...") 
    c.connect(hostname = "inserthostname", username = None, password = "insert pw" ,pkey = k) 
    print ("connected!!!") 
    stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('ls')
    c.close() 
    
file_move()
```

Comment: Share the snippet of what was run that produced the error.

Comment: I tried it on my terminal as well using the standard procedures and that didn’t work either. Is there any way to convert my pem file to a public key?

Comment: `
import paramiko

def file_move():
            k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("Insertadress")
            c = paramiko.SSHClient()
            c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            print ("connecting...")
            c.connect(hostname = "inserthostname", username = None, password = "insert pw" ,pkey = k)
            print ("connected!!!")
            stdin, stdout, stderr = c.exec_command('ls')
            c.close()

file_move() `

@abhishekphukan

Comment: Here's how to extract the public key from the .pem file using ssh-keygen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38401773/45978

Answer (score 1):

Paramiko does not seem to have an API for extracting the public key from a private key, but since you are welcoming non-Python solutions too, here is a command line version:

```sh
ssh-keygen -y -f myprivatekey
```

where `myprivatekey` is the file containing your private key (named `Insertaddress` in the question).

This outputs the public key on standard output.

Tested on Linux (where the command is provided by the package `openssh-client`), but should work on a Mac too.