# Deleted key-pairs from AWS console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have mistakenly deleted key pairs of a EC2 instances from aws console however I kept .pem file saved in my local system is there any way to get those deleted key pairs back?

[image]

I've tried to go through the documents but it suggested that creating an Amazon Machine Image(AMI) and it doesn't seems to be eligible for free tier usage hence not trying it for the time being.

Comment: You will be able to login to the instance just fine. You only need keypairs showing in the EC2 Management Console if you wish to launch new instances that use those keypairs. The big warning on your screen is saying that the local `.pem` file has permissions that are too open. Running `chmod 600 myserver.pem` should fix that warning. Give that a try and let us know how it goes!

Comment: And if you have the PEM files, you can [re-create the public keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401719/how-do-i-get-the-public-key-of-a-pem-file) from those files and re-create the EC2 keypairs by importing the public keys into EC2.